# Search a treeView item

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview

Is it possible to convert the `GetTreeViewItem(ItemsControl container, object item)` Methode from this microsoft example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff407130(v=vs.110).aspx, to use a string instead of an object, as second parameter. Because i want to find a TreeViewItem in my TreeView based on a string input. I am not quite sure how to convert my search string to an object, so that it still works.
(The link is german but you can set the language to english)

**Background of why I need this function and not something else**:

(It is also explained on the microsoft page itself, but here is my specifc problem)

I have coded a XML-Viewer, which display the xml-text in a TreeView. The Binding Source is a XmlDocument. All works fine, but now I have to implement a search function. The Problem I have is that I could search the xmlDocument, but I can not make the search result visable in the viewer. I can not just make something like `searchResultNode.IsSelected = true`, because it has no IsSelected Property. Thats why i need to search the visual Tree, to get a result where I can set the isSelected property. But because of performance reasons it won't load the whole visual Tree, only a small part for displaying, thats why i need this example function to work for me.